# Two letter abbreviated weekday name

Tags: time, date

Running `$ date` produces `Mo 15 Nov 2021 18:02:27 CET`. Apparently the standard weekday name should have three letters, i.e. `Mon` in this case, and it is causing some problems with one software I'm using.

Is the behavior of `date` on my system normal? Should it print `Mo` or `Mon`. If the latter, how can I fix this?

---

**edit:**

The output of `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

And `locale -k LC_TIME`

```
abday="So;Mo;Di;Mi;Do;Fr;Sa"
day="Sonntag;Montag;Dienstag;Mittwoch;Donnerstag;Freitag;Samstag"
abmon="Jän;Feb;Mär;Apr;Mai;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Okt;Nov;Dez"
mon="Jänner;Februar;März;April;Mai;Juni;Juli;August;September;Oktober;November;Dezember"
...
```

Ok, it seems to be some German/Austrian/Netherlands convention to use two letter weekday names.

Comment: AFAIK the default is to use the values defined by your system's current locale - please [edit] your question to include the outputs of commands `locale` and `locale -k LC_TIME`

Comment: de_DE, fy_NL seems to be to using *two-letter* short name,  you may change the locale for a single command with `LC_TIME=C date`

Comment: Thanks, I think both of these comments more or less qualify for answer. I just went to Region & Language settings and changed from Austrian format to UK format.